# Is mysql_* deprecated after PDO was introduced?

Tags: php, mysql, deprecation

I have been noticing for a long time on Stack Overflow that most users recommend to use PDO instead of `mysql_*`, because PDO is more secure than `mysql_*`. But my question is if websites which are already running with `mysql_*` will stops working? Or what exactly does "deprecating" mean here? So should we have never used  `mysql_*`? From which PHP version is is deprecated?

Comment: It should be. But the people behind Zend are very conservative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [PHP.net page FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  It answers your question and gives migration advice.

Your code won't suddenly stop working unless when PHP remove the functionality, you upgrade your PHP version.  The FAQ page advice recommends you write new code using one of the alternatives.  If it's not a massive job, it could be worth considering switching.. that depends on your project though.

Answer (score 1):

The websites written with mysql_* functions shall continue to work until PHP removes the functionality altogether. As of now, the functions are merely depreciated.

Deprecated means that those functions are no longer recommended, and are replaced with better functions. They may have no support either.

It's recommended to switch over to PDO mainly because of the security that it provides with injection based attacks.